# Pandas zfill multiple items in single cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple values in a single cell

```
Q3
1 4
1 3
3 4 11 
3 4 6 15 16
```

How can I zfill or pad to add leading zeros to each value in each cell?

```
df['Q3'].str.split(' ').apply(lambda x: x.zfill(8))
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'zfill'

looking for

```
Q3
00000001 00000004
00000001 00000003
00000003 00000004 00000011 
00000003 00000004 00000006 00000015 00000016
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. `Split` the values then apply `zfill` on each value and `join` back

```
df['Q3'].map(lambda x: ' '.join(y.zfill(8) for y in x.split()))
```

---

```
0                               00000001 00000004
1                               00000001 00000003
2                      00000003 00000004 00000011
3    00000003 00000004 00000006 00000015 00000016
Name: Q3, dtype: object
```

Comment: updated my question to show the output I am looking for.  Want to keep the same values in each cell just pad them with zeros

Comment: Thank you this is great but this generates a separate object, how can I roll this back into my dataframe column?

Comment: Assign the result to column `df['Q3'] = df['Q3'].map(lambda x: ' '.join(y.zfill(8) for y in x.split()))`